# C: Inserting element into an array of structs

Tags: c, struct, insert, hashtable

I have an array of structs where each array element is:

```
struct Item {
  int code;
  char * label;
};
```

The array itself is a global variable:

```
struct Item * ht[SIZE];
```

This is how I currently insert an item into the array:

```
void insert(int toadd, char *toput) {

   struct Item *item = (struct Item*) malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
   item->label = toput;  
   item->code = toadd;

   int hashIndex = 0; 

   //move in array until an empty or deleted cell
   while(ht[hashIndex] != NULL && ht[hashIndex]->code != -1) {
      //go to next cell
      ++hashIndex;

      //wrap around the table
      hashIndex %= SIZE;
   }

   ht[hashIndex] = item;
}
```

In another function, I call the insert method, followed with some printf statements to check what's going on:

```
insert(ctr, trimwhitespace(line2));
printf("\nAdding to ht: String: %s Integer: %d\n", trimwhitespace(line2), ctr);

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    if (ht[i] != NULL)
    printf("\nThis is what's inside ht: String: %s Integer: %d\n", ht[i] -> label, ht[i] -> code);            
}
```

This is an example of the output:

Adding to ht: String: four Integer: 6

This is what's inside ht: String: four Integer: 0

This is what's inside ht: String: four Integer: 4

This is what's inside ht: String: four Integer: 5

This is what's inside ht: String: four Integer: 6

As you can see, the struct is being inserted multiple times, with different integer values.

I think this is unlikely to be an issue with the loops that the `insert` call is in, as the first print statement would also be printed multiple times if the `insert` call was being made multiple times. But I may be wrong.

How do I make sure that the `insert` method only inserts the struct once and not multiple times? 
Or does the problem lie elsewhere?

Comment: How have you initialized everything? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Shouldn't you call a hash function somewhere? Otherwise this whole code is kind of meaningless.

Comment: `while` loop in `insert()` will be infinite when all the cells are filled (this does not apply to the question, but it is important)

Comment: Perhaps some of `ht` was pointing to a location where the memory was interpreted to be pointing to the same place as your string is stored, however unlikely that may be. Either way, if you're changing **one** entry of `ht` and **four** of them are not `NULL`, then obviously something wasn't initialized properly.

Comment: Here's how I'd do further debugging: add a print before `ht[hashIndex] = item;` to make 100% sure that only one of them is changed, and change the `printf("\nThis is what's inside[...]` to also output `i`. The first one should have a value of 0 and it's going to be interesting to see what the other ones are.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that adding an `if` statement right before my `insert` method call, to check whether the particular key was already inserted earlier, solved the problem, though this may not be the most ideal fix:

```
if (!containsKey(trimwhitespace(stringcopy3))) {           

      insert(ctr, trimwhitespace(stringcopy3));
      printf("\nAdding to ht: String: %s Integer: %d\n", trimwhitespace(stringcopy3), ctr);

}
```

I'm still not sure why multiple instances of the key were being inserted in the first place, but this is a temporary solution.

Comment: You don't provide the  [mcve] in the question and you add some fix in the code that is not shown as part of the question and you answer yourself. This does not make sense and not at all useful for further readers.